# "Extract Odd & Even Pages" fails: command line tool returned error 127

Tags: macos, automator

I'm trying to whip up a quick & dirty solution to manual duplex printing with automator. It always fails at the "Extract Odd & Even Pages" step no matter which PDF I throw at it.

The automator script is as follows:

[image: Automator script]

Log:

```
** Automator Workflow Log: /Users/lilywhite/Library/PDF Services/Manual Duplex.workflow **

2022-12-19 12:15:50 +0000: Get Specified Finder Items completed
2022-12-19 12:15:50 +0000: Conversion from Files/Folders to PDF files completed
2022-12-19 12:15:50 +0000: Extract Odd & Even Pages failed - 1 error
2022-12-19 12:15:50 +0000: Command line tool returned error 127.: 127
```

FYI: I've made a simple Perl script to achieve manual duplex. Though unrelated to the question, I'm putting it here in case it helps somebody:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.36;

use PDF::API2;

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
    say "Processing $file:";
    my $source_pdf = PDF::API2->open($file);
    my $odd_pdf = PDF::API2->new();
    my $even_pdf = PDF::API2->new();
  $source_pdf->page() if ($source_pdf->page_count() % 2 == 1);
    my $n = $source_pdf->page_count();
    for (my $i = 1, my $j = ($n % 2 == 0 ? $n : $n - 1); $i <= $n && $j >= 0; $i += 2, $j -= 2) {
        $even_pdf->import_page($source_pdf, $j, $even_pdf->page_count() + 1);
        $odd_pdf->import_page($source_pdf, $i, $odd_pdf->page_count() + 1);
    }
    $even_pdf->save("${file}_even.pdf");
    $odd_pdf->save("${file}_odd.pdf");
    say "Done.";
    say "Start printing odd pages";
    system "lp '${file}_odd.pdf'" and die "Printing failed";    # shells return 0 on success
    print "Done, continue printing even pages? (y/N) ";
    chomp(my $answer = <STDIN>);
    die "Abort" unless (lc($answer) eq 'y');
    say "Start printing even pages";
    system "lp '${file}_even.pdf'" and die "Printing failed";
    say "Done!";
}
```

Comment: What OS version are you on? Several of the Automator PDF actions used python scripts, even after python was removed in Monterey 12.3. So they would fail instantly. I think they've been fixed in Ventura.

Comment: 12.4. I think I know why: I've nuked Python2 sometimes before and got pyenv to manage python versions. I'll try to get Ventura today.

Comment: The Automator python scripts call /usr/bin/python, which no longer exists in 12.4. There is no python2 to 'nuke'. (And you couldn't get rid of the system python, even when it existed.)

Comment: Also: does your printer driver not have a manual duplex option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several of the Automator actions for PDF manipulation in Monterey (and earlier) rely on python2 scripts. When Apple removed python2 from the OS in Monterey 12.3, they did not update the actions.

The actions have now been rewritten in Ventura.

The affected actions are:

- Add Grid to PDF
- Combine PDF
- Extract Odd & Even Pages